# Passing objects from node to the front end

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to pass an array to the front end (javascript) using node.

I'm passing country names from a mysql db into a .geocode call. Currently however I can't seem to append the whole thing into an array/object, and then pass that to the render method to show on the front end. It's always empty.

Js

```
//route for homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  let sql = "SELECT country_name from countries";
  let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;


    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      geoLoc = []

      const promises = results.map(result => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        geo.geocode('mapbox.places', result.Country_Name, function (err, geoData) {
          if(err) reject()
          if(geoData){
            resolve(geoData.features[0])
          };
        });
      }))

      Promise.all(promises).then((geoLoc) => {
        res.render('layouts/layout', {
          results: geoLoc
        });
      })


  }

  });
});
```

First console

```
[ { id: 'country.11971821457735890',
    type: 'Feature',
    place_type: [ 'country' ],
    relevance: 1,
    properties: { short_code: 'bj', wikidata: 'Q962' },
    text: 'Benin',
    place_name: 'Benin',
    bbox: [ 0.776667, 6.13014, 3.843051, 12.408444 ],
    center: [ 2.18333, 8.83333 ],
    geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] } },
  { id: 'country.8605848117814600',
    type: 'Feature',
    place_type: [ 'country' ],
    relevance: 1,
    properties: { short_code: 'gb', wikidata: 'Q145' },
    text: 'United Kingdom',
    place_name: 'United Kingdom',
    bbox: [ -8.718659, 49.802665, 1.867399, 60.945453 ],
    center: [ -2, 54 ],
    geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Array] } } ]
```

The second console just shows an empty array.

Comment: database calls are async in nature. So you will need to user async await or something like that

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:

Your res.render() needs to wait, till your `geoLoc` is accumulated.
Your can try promise as suggested by @Sayegh or callbacks.

You can even use something like this, but Promise or callback will be a suitable option

```
geo.geocode("mapbox.places", results[i].Country_Name, function(err, geoData) {
    if (geoData) {
        geoLoc.push(geoData.features[0]);
        console.log(geoLoc);
    }
});

if(geoLoc){
    res.render('layouts/layout', {
      results: geoLoc
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It still seems to be an empty array however.

Comment: He doesn't have one geocode request, he has many of them which are in a loop. So this would not work in this case

Comment: I see, okay thanks for the reply. I've updated my OP. I think the way i'm calling the sql query is messing with everything

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `geocode` function is asynchronous, and the geocode functions will call their callbacks after the render function is called with what was an empty array at that point in time.

You need to wait for all the requests to finish, then call `res.render`.

It's also a lot easier to do with promises.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT country_name from countries";
  conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const promises = results.map(result => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      geo.geocode('mapbox.places', result.Country_Name, function (err, geoData) {
        if(err) reject()
        if(geoData){
          resolve(geoData.features[0])
        };
      });
    }))
    Promise.all(promises).then((geoLoc) => {
      res.render('layouts/layout', {
        results: geoLoc
      });
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: I see that makes sense. I feel like yours would work but I'm maybe doing things too weirdly. I've updated my OP to show the whole app.get method.

Comment: Not too weird, but you'll find that switching to promises and async functions can make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Yea i'm seeing the benefits. Thanks for the tip defo needing to refactor alot of my thinking. I get the following error with your updated code which i'll show in my op

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: C:\Users\Any User\views\layouts\layout.hbs: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)

Comment: That's because you need to replace the loop completely with my answer

Comment: You'll notice I used `results.map` which loops over each result, so the loop is no longer needed

Comment: Ah fab thankyou, sorry what a blunder on my behalf. It's passing the object to the front end, i just need to figure out now how to make it appear on a mapbox map.

Comment: Glad I can help :) also on a side note, look up knexjs. You'll like it. https://knexjs.org. If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted answer so other people who see this question would know.

Answer (score 0):

Call is asynchronous so access geoLoc inside callback.

```
geoLoc = []
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

  geo.geocode('mapbox.places', results[i].Country_Name, function (err, geoData) {


    geoLoc.push(geoData.features[0])
    console.log(geoLoc)
    console.log('second',geoLoc)

    res.render('layouts/layout', {
        results: geoLoc
    }); 
  });

}
```

Comment: I get the following error 

    if (err) return req.next(err);
TypeError: req.next is not a function